# Safari issue when rendering strokes using stroke-dasharray

Tags: html, css, svg, stroke, stroke-dasharray

I am animating some strokes belonging to an arrow icon, which works great in all browsers (including IE11), with exception to Safari. For some reason, Safari is rendering small black flecks when `stroke` dashes are set to `0` in a `stroke-dasharray` rule. My code is below:

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--arrow-right" height="24px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24px">
  <g>
    <path class="stroke stroke--1" d="M4,12 L19.3,12"></path>
    <polyline class="stroke stroke--2" points="15.05 7.76 19.3 12 15.05 16.24"></polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```css
.icon {
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 15.29;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 15.29 0;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 6.5 0 6.5;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 13 0;
}
```

Run the snippet below in Safari to recreate the issue.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.icon');

el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.icon {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 15.29;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 15.29 0;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 6.5 0 6.5;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 13 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button below to toggle the <code>.active</code> class.</p>
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--arrow-right" height="24px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24px">
  <g>
    <path class="stroke stroke--1" d="M4,12 L19.3,12"></path>
    <polyline class="stroke stroke--2" points="15.05 7.76 19.3 12 15.05 16.24"></polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
<p>In Safari, you will see black flecks where <code>stroke</code> dash lengths are set to <code>0</code> when the icon is not active.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening in Safari, and how to resolve it, so that the black flecks are not visible when a `stroke-dash` is set to `0`.

Comment: If you think you've found a webkit bug [report it here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: I can do. Wouldn't this be apparent in Chrome, then too, though?

Comment: Safari is WebKit chrome is blink. Blink separated from WebKit a long time ago. Common issues are pretty rare these days

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. For some reason, I had my wires crossed and thought Chrome had switched from Blink to WebKit.

Comment: @danMad If you do report this bug, please link it here for future reference.

Comment: Based on the answer below, there is no WebKit bug. I was inaccurate in my coordinate declarations, and so the flecks were present. If anything, Safari is actually more correct than other browsers in the way that my icons were being rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what is the issue here, sounds like Safari doesn't really like all this floating coordinates, but your values also sounds quite weird.

Anyway, using a tiny offset for the first value of the polyline's dash-array then using precise values for others will make Safari happy:

(note that I got these values by using Safari's result from each element's `getTotalLength()`)

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.icon');

el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.icon {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 15.3;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 15.3 0;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0.0001 6.003 0.0001 6.003;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 13 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button below to toggle the <code>.active</code> class.</p>
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--arrow-right" height="240px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="240px">
  <g>
    <path class="stroke stroke--1" d="M4,12 L19.3,12"></path>
    <polyline class="stroke stroke--2" points="15.05 7.76 19.3 12 15.05 16.24"></polyline>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. Your solution appears to solve the problem, which is awesome. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'Your values seem quite weird'? I have a whole host of icons I need to apply your example to. So I want to make sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Well from here it sounds you used quite arbitrary values. For instance your <path> draws an horizontal line from x:4 to x:19.3 that's a 15.3 line, not a 15.29 one. Same for the polyline, 6.5 is relatively far from the real 6.003339767456055 that each segment of this polyline measure. So if you have to make several such icons, then try to use as precise values as you can. And to get these values, you can use the [SVGGeometry.getTotalLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) method.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I blame the GUI I used to create the icons. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this sort of animations by changing the value of the `stroke-dashoffset`instead of animating the `stroke-dasharray` value. Please note I've changes the polygon with a path where you move twice to the tip of the arrow.
This is fixing the issue you have on Safari.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.icon');

el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.icon {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 15.3;
  stroke-dashoffset: 15.3;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.icon--arrow-right .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 6.22;
  stroke-dashoffset: 6.22;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.icon--arrow-right.active .stroke--2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button below to toggle the <code>.active</code> class.</p>
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--arrow-right" height="240px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="240px">
  <g>
    <path class="stroke stroke--1" d="M4,12 L19.3,12"></path>
    <!--<polyline class="stroke stroke--2" points="15.05 7.76 19.3 12 15.05 16.24"></polyline>-->
    
     <path class="stroke stroke--2" d="M19.3,12.3L15.05, 7.76M19.3,11.7L15.05, 16.24" />
  </g>
</svg>
<p>In Safari, you will see black flecks where <code>stroke</code> dash lengths are set to <code>0</code> when the icon is not active.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with using stroke-dashoffset is that it would not be supported properly in IE11. Which is why I am using stroke-dasharray as a work-around. Thank you for your answer, though.